# Don't understand where the image redirects me

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a batch which takes you to a link, but this is not the problem, the problem is that I'm trying to get the link from the website and I don't know why I'm bad. I explain it better, in the website there is an image, this image takes you to the place I want. This is the image code. Forget the cookie, I only want the place which this image takes you to.

```
<div id="x" class="votes" style="height:30px;">
<img src="images/image.png" id="y"></div>
```

Going down, we have this code:

```
<script>
("#y").click(function () {
  $.post("z.php",{id:100},function(exit){
    $("#x").html(exit);
  }
);
</script>
```

Ok, the problem is that when I'm in the website, for example www.h.com/i.php?id=100 (which has the code I showed you) and I change the url to /i.php?id=100 for /z.php?id=100 (what I thought the website does) I get this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1.

But if you click the image.png in the web, the web does what I'm trying to do with urls... I don't know if you understand me, sorry for my English and my explanations.

Comment: Looks like you've succeeded with SQL injection

Comment: yeah, your english is bad :) no clue, what you are trying to say.

Comment: As the error relates to an SQL statement, I would have thought it was obvious that you have to **show the SQL statement** the error relates to.

Answer (score 1):

You can't interchange a GET and POST request. Something that looks like this is a GET request:

```
www.h.com/i.php?id=100
```

Also, you should take a look at your `z.php`. There is something wrong with how it handles your SQL query. It could be a typo causing a syntax error. Most probably, you missed escaping a quote, forgot a quote or your opening and closing quotes don't match.

Answer (score 0):

Yea, you can't use POST if z.php actually responds to GET.  Assuming that z.php actually responds to GET, jQuery's load function is more suitable for you since you want to populate a div with the ajax result.

Haven't tried it, but try the below:

```
<script>
("#y").click(function () {
    $("#x").load("z.php", {id:100});
  });
</script>
```

In reply to your comment:

> is there any way for do what the code does without clicking the image?

Yes. If you want to do the action without the user click, you can try just this:

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $("#x").load("z.php", {id:100});
});
</script>
```

I think now I understand your question about batch.  In javascript you can run a batch program anywhere you like.  Just put the javascript lines / batch inside the script tag.

```
<script>
  //... Your program comes here (batch)
</script>
```

But the batch should run only after resources/images are loaded. So you can run the program/batch after document load is complete, like this.

```
<script>
  $(function() {
     //... Your program comes here (batch)
  });
</script>
```

To understand more about this, google about "javascript document load" or "javascript on load". Jquery gives a feature to detect document load using `$(function(){ /* ... */ });` as show in the above.

Comment: Ty, but, is there any way for do what the code does without clicking the image? I haven't explained well, okay your answers helped me because i didn't see the diference but, the thing is that the website is not mine, and i'm trying to do what clicnking in the image does by a batch file, i don't know if it is possible..